# Can I use Fit/Fitnesse to test a .NET application?

Tags: .net, fitnesse

Has anyone tried that? What's your experience?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Fit/Fitnesse does have a .NET runner. We use it everyday and I have to say that It works very well and we have been quite successful with it. We currently have several hundred test pages with 10,000+ assertions. Our product owners are engaging our developers to write tests. The tests are hoked up to CI, we have a inMemory mode so developers can get fast feedback on failures and a slower mode for full stack integration.

It also has the awesome side effect of forcing developers to keep logic out of the UI. I honestly would not want to program .Net without it...or something like it.

**EDIT FOR QUESTION **
you just have to define the .NET test runner as your runner and add your applications bin to classpath. Another odd thing you might run into is that your fixtures can't have namespaces (there may be a way around this but I don't know it). So the front of your wiki should have something like this:

```
variable defined: COMMAND_PATTERN=%m %p
variable defined: TEST_RUNNER=dotnet\FitServer.exe
variable defined: PATH_SEPARATOR=;

classpath: .\..\..\FrontEnd\Fixtures\bin\Debug\*.dll
classpath: .\dotnet\*.dll
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a link to a how-to, I just couldn't find that on the official site...

Comment: You can use namespaces with fixtures:

1) Put fully qualified fixture name in table:

!|MyNameSpace.MyFixture|

2) Use import fixture:
|import|
|MyNameSpace|

|myfixture|

3) Use suite configuration file: http://www.syterra.com/FitSharp/SuiteConfigurationFile.html

Answer (score 5):

This is where the latest info is: http://fitsharp.github.com

Answer (score 3):

[How do I setup FitNesse for use with .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828919/how-do-i-setup-fitnesse-for-use-with-net)

Answer (score 0):

useful link if you are working with .Net4
http://bhenderson.blogspot.ca/2010/06/fitsharp-with-net-40-hangs-fitnesse.html