# How do I setup FitNesse for use with .NET?

Tags: .net, testing, installation, automated-tests, fitnesse

I'm trying to get started with FitNesse for .NET on Windows Vista. In all tutorials I find on the web I'm told to execute the run.bat file, but all i get when downloading the latest release is a .jar-file. When i run this, the filestructure is unpacked and I can reach the fitnesse server by browsing to http://localhost.
Now, when I'm trying to set up a test project, according to all documentation I find I'm supposed define the path to fitsharp.dll but I can't find this file anywhere in the filestructure that was set up from the .jar-file. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 27):

Download FitNesse jar from http://fitnesse.org/.

Run

```
java -jar fitnesse.jar
```

It will start web server and create folder `FitNesseRoot` with wiki contents. To check that it has started navigate to `http://localhost` - you should see FitNesse front page.

Edit front page - just add something like *HelloWorldTest* (must be camel case!) in the bottom and save.
Click on the appeared question mark and save a new page.
Click *Properties* and make sure **Page type** is *Test*.

Download `FitSharp` from https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp and extract it to folder **fitsharp** next to your `FitNesseRoot`.

Create .Net project for tests, add references to **fit.dll** and **fitSharp.dll** located in just created *fitsharp* folder.

Write a simple test in .Net and compile it. For example use a simple column fixture as described on http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.BasicFitFixtures.ColumnFixture. Add test table to our *HelloWorldTest* page.

On top of your FitNesse test page (in our example *HelloWorldTest*) enter:

```
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,fitsharp\fit.dll %p}
!define TEST_RUNNER {fitsharp\Runner.exe}
!path <path to your test assembly>
```

If you click on `Test` button and see no results then try to use `TEST_RUNNER` `RunnerW.exe` for troubleshooting.

Here's a great book on using FitNesse with .Net: http://fitnesse.s3.amazonaws.com/tdd_net_with_fitnesse.pdf

Comment: I spent hours trying to get this working. The trick seems to be putting the FitSharp directory NEXT TO the FitNesseRoot directory. NOTE: I had FitSharp under FitNesseRoot, but fitsharp\Runner.exe was FileNotFound, so I tried supplying an abolute path, that was FileNotFound coz the path 'C:\Programs\FitNesse\FitNesseRoot\FitSharp\RunnerW.exe' was being TRUNCATED. Arrrggghhh!

Comment: Important note: download packages by using NuGet instead of direct downloading to have runner libraries up to date. So, right-click on the Visual Studio projects, Nuget Packages, type in the search box "FitNesse". You will see the list of all packages available.

Answer (score 11):

Checkout this free ebook: [Test Driven .NET Development With FitNesse: Second Edition](http://gojko.net/fitnesse/book/)

It will show you everything you need, from how to set up FitNesse with FitSharp, to best practices.

You'll need to get the FitSharp dll from http://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/downloads.

Answer (score 5):

The .NET code is no longer bundled with FitNesse and is available here: http://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/downloads

Here's some information to get you started: http://fitsharp.github.com

Answer (score 2):

Goto your `http://localhost/root` (special page for FitNesse) and paste this in there:

```
variable defined: COMMAND_PATTERN=%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,dotnet2\fit.dll %p
variable defined: TEST_RUNNER=dotnet2\Runner.exe
variable defined: PATH_SEPARATOR=;
classpath: dotnet2\*.dll
```

Unzip the FitSharp binaries into a folder called `dotnet2` under the folder you unpacked FitNesse.

FitSharp also includes DbFit for MSSQL & Oracle testing.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this article:

http://www.programgood.net/2009/10/21/TestDrivenDevelopmentInNETCustomerTestsTheWebServiceUsingFitnesseCh7.aspx

This may help..let me know how you go.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't unpacked the .jar file, you need to run:  java -jar fitnesse.jar.  If you got that far, then follow jediwhale's very good tutorial.  Here's a second, similar, tutorial, too:  http://schuchert.wikispaces.com/FitNesse.Tutorials.CSharp.Slim.EachTable

Answer (score 0):

I wrote step-by-step guide here: https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Net-Runner-tutorial

Short idea:
1. Install FitNesse (just copy it to the any directory)
2. Start FitNesse
3. Use NuGet (!) to retrieve one of the packages (NetRunner or FitSharp, any of them)
4. Write functions needed in the Visual Studio
5. Write functions calls in the FitNesse opened

Fill free to ask more questions on the wiki page above.