# How to start fitnesse tests from ms test

Tags: c#, mstest, fitnesse

I can see that it can be done from JUnit,
I would like to run it from ms test framework instead.
It is probably very similar.

thanks
Kenneth

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828919/how-do-i-setup-fitnesse-for-use-with-net check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am/was thinking that the easiest would be to write a unit test suite, containing a testmethod that starts fitness up as in another process. I.e. run it from command line and getting the result from the output file.

not a ver unit testing way, since it is slow. It sound more like an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

There is no FitNesse runner for MSTest at this time.  The biggest hurdle is that the FitNesse test engine is written in Java and was therefore easier to integrate with JUnit.  To do the same with MSTest would require porting significant portions of Java code to .NET.  If there is widespread demand for this, open source developers may be encouraged to work on it.